# Why are the output of these two java programs different

Tags: java, multiprocessing, volatile, cpu-cache, memory-barriers

```java
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class VolatileDemo1 {
    private static Object stop;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ignore){}
            stop = new Object();
        });
        t.start();
        while (stop == null);
        System.out.println("finish");
    }
}
```

VolatileDemo1  will not print finish

```java
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class VolatileDemo2 {
    private static Object stop;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ignore){}
            stop = new Object();
        });
        t.start();
        while (stop == null)
            TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.sleep(1);
        System.out.println("finish");
    }
}
```

VolatileDemo2  will print finish，why?

I am learning the usage of the volatile keyword in Java. I understand that in demo1, the variable "stop" not being declared as volatile prevents the correct printing of "finish". However, I am confused as to why demo2 does not use volatile but is still able to print "finish". How is this possible?

Comment: What's the difference between them?  You talk about `volatile`, but neither of them uses `volatile` except in the class name.  Oh, in the spin loop?  Apparently making a library function call in practice stops the compiler from hoisting the load of `stop` out of the loop.  Basically the same problem as in C++ [MCU programming - C++ O2 optimization breaks while loop](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/387181) (but Java `volatile` is like C++ `atomic`)

Comment: I'm not sure, but likely the use of sleep here introduces some form of visibility fence which makes the update to `stop` visible to the main thread. The fact that volatile will make this work, does not mean that the absence of volatile will cause things like this to never work, you just can't rely on it, which is why you **should** use volatile.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: Yup, it probably ends up calling a non-inline library function that's opaque to the optimizer, so it needs memory in sync with the abstract machine.  i.e. function calls that don't inline are visibility fences, at least for any object that might be globally reachable.  And yeah, "not guaranteed to work" is very different from "guaranteed to fail", just like C++ undefined behaviour where code like this would "work" in a debug build.  (JVMs don't have an anti-optimized mode, but if they did, it would make every iteration reload, and CPU caches are coherent.)

Comment: Example from [JLS 17.3. Sleep and Yield](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.3): "assume that `this.done` is a non-volatile boolean field: `while (!this.done)  Thread.sleep(1000);` The compiler is free to read the field `this.done` just once, and reuse the cached value in each execution of the loop. This would mean that the loop would never terminate, even if another thread changed the value of `this.done`."